# How can I disable internal speakers on imacs in computer lab but still have sound enabled for headphones

Tags: audio, headphones, speakers

I have around a dozen imacs running el capitan in a public setting and need to find a way to disable the internal speakers so customers cannot play music ect and distract others. Sound cannot be completely disabled since users are allowed to use headphones. Also, I need to find a way that is not necessarily easy for the user to go in and revert the external sound back on.  I've researched this issue and haven't really found a solution for this issue since these are public computers and are not being used by myself alone..aka the user will try to turn the sound back on. Is there a solution for this that anyone has come up with? If anyone has any tips please be very descriptive.

Thanks!

Comment: Using wire cutters on one of the speaker leads should so the job. Less drastically, you could set sound output to headphones in System prefs, the use your awesome Admin powers to send that prefs pane to the trash.

Comment: I tried to figure this out a few years ago in a public lab at my elementary/high school, but I found that it is impossible without actually disconnecting the internal speakers. In our case, disciplinary action quelled the most egregious malefactors from repeating their offense. This [Reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/2l9m6k/is_there_a_way_to_disable_the_internal_speakers/) has an answer by "Plastonic" that may help. I've not tried it.